# Algorithm to schedule weighted events, with different amount of participants to limited set of rooms

Tags: scheduled-tasks, dynamic-programming, backtracking

I've been reading tons of material about dynamic programming, back tracking, linear programming, etc but cant seem to find or understand what type of algorithm best suits my problem.

The problem:
I have a list of events, each are given a priority based on some condition (irrelevant to the question). Each event has a start & end time, plus the number of participants.
I have a list of meeting rooms and each meeting room has a capacity (number representing how many participants it can hold). Given this constraint, each event has an additional list, which represents the potential meeting rooms it can be assigned to (meeting room capacity - event participants > 0).
The algorithm only runs for the events of the current day, so its constrained to the 24 hours of a day.

Additional constraints:

- It doesnt matter if an event cant be assigned
- An event cant be assigned if it means another event with greater priority is left with no available room in their potential room list

In conclusion, the idea is to assign the maximum number of events we can, given that no event with greater priority than any of the assigned ones has no room. The return value shouldnt be a number representing this number, but a list for each room that holds the events that were actually assigned to it

Comment: Since you already know the priority of your events, it looks like a greedy solution would give the optimal answer. No need for backtracking or dynamic programming. Consider the events in decreasing order of priority. For each event: find the smallest room that is available on the time period of the event and has the required capacity, if there is one.

Comment: Hello Stef, thanks for your answer!

But imagine this scenario:

- Event A, can go either to room X or Y. Room X is smaller than room Y, so assuming A is the event with the topmost priority, i would allocate it in Room X

- Event B can only go to room X. Since Room X was occupied by Event A in the previous iteration it would be determined that Event B cant be allocated, when in fact it can. At this point the algorithm should check if A has any other free room available and if it has then move Event A to that other room (Y in this case) and allocate Event B to Room X, otherwise do nothing

Comment: Ooooh, you're right. It's a lot less obvious than I thought.